# Is it a Hamiltonian cycle on a grid?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, grid

A Hamiltonian path in a graph is a path that visits each vertex exactly once; a Hamiltonian cycle is a Hamiltonian path that is a cycle – the path forms a simple closed loop. In this challenge the graph will be a `n x n` grid, where n is an even number greater than 2.
Here is an example of a Hamiltonian cycle on 12x12 rectangular grid:

```
+---------------+   +-----------------------+
|               |   |                       |
+-----------+   |   +---+   +-----------+   |
            |   |       |   |           |   |
+-------+   |   +---+   |   +-------+   |   |
|       |   |       |   |           |   |   |
|   +---+   |   +---+   |   +-------+   +---+
|   |       |   |       |   |               
|   +-------+   +---+   |   +---------------+
|                   |   |                   |
+---+   +-------+   |   |   +-----------+   |
    |   |       |   |   |   |           |   |
+---+   +---+   |   +---+   +---+   +---+   |
|           |   |               |   |       |
+---+   +---+   |   +-----------+   +---+   |
    |   |       |   |                   |   |
+---+   +---+   |   +---+   +-------+   |   |
|           |   |       |   |       |   |   |
+-------+   |   +-------+   +---+   |   |   |
        |   |                   |   |   |   |
+-------+   |   +---------------+   +---+   |
|           |   |                           |
+-----------+   +---------------------------+
```

The path visits each vertex exactly once and forms a simple closed loop that do not intersect or touches itself. The grid points are not shown so that the ASCII graphic is not cluttered. There are three `-` (`---`) between two horizontally connected vertices or 3 spaces if the vertices are not connected.  A single `|` connects two vertically adjacent vertices, spaces are used otherwise. Since the grid is not visible, the `+` is used only where the path takes a turn. The path will never be broken - if a segment connects two vertices, it will be `---` and never `- -`.

### Task:

You will be given an ASCII representation of a path and you need to check if it is a Hamiltonian cycle on a grid. Write a full program or a function that solves this problem.

### Input:

ASCII representation of a path. It can be:
-   A mutliline string;
-   A list of strings
-   A list/array of characters
or any format that is convenient for you.
You can have an optional parameter `n` for the size of the grid.
You can use alternatve ASCII representation, just explain it.

### Output:

- A consistent value indicating that the path is a Hamiltonian cycle on a grid
- A consistent value indicating that the path is not a Hamiltonian cycle on a grid. There can be several reasons for this: The path doesn’t visit all vertices; the path crosses/touches itself; there are two or more paths and not a single one. You don’t need to specify the reason – just return/print a consistent falsy value.

### Test cases:

Truthy:

```
Optional `n` = 6

+-----------+   +---+
|           |   |   |
|   +-------+   |   |
|   |           |   |
|   +-----------+   |
|                   |
+---+   +-------+   |
    |   |       |   |
+---+   +---+   |   |
|           |   |   |
+-----------+   +---+

+-------------------+
|                   |
|   +---------------+
|   |               
|   |   +-----------+
|   |   |           |
|   |   |   +---+   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   +---+   |   |   |
|           |   |   |
+-----------+   +---+

+---+   +-----------+
|   |   |           |
|   |   |   +-------+
|   |   |   |       
|   |   |   +-------+
|   |   |           |
|   +---+   +-------+
|           |       
|   +---+   +-------+
|   |   |           |
+---+   +-----------+


Optional `n` = 8

+---------------------------+
|                           |
+---+   +-----------+   +---+
    |   |           |   |   
+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+
|           |   |           |
|   +---+   |   +---+   +---+
|   |   |   |       |   |   
+---+   |   +---+   |   +---+
        |       |   |       |
+---+   +-------+   +---+   |
|   |                   |   |
|   +-------------------+   |
|                           |
+---------------------------+

+-------------------+   +---+
|                   |   |   |
+-------+   +---+   |   |   |
        |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+   |   |   |   +---+   |
|   |   |   |   |           |
|   |   +---+   |   +---+   |
|   |           |   |   |   |
|   +-----------+   |   |   |
|                   |   |   |
+---+   +-----------+   |   |
    |   |               |   |
+---+   +-----------+   |   |
|                   |   |   |
+-------------------+   +---+

+---+   +-------------------+
|   |   |                   |
|   |   +---+   +-----------+
|   |       |   |           
|   +---+   |   +-----------+
|       |   |               |
|   +---+   +---+   +---+   |
|   |           |   |   |   |
|   +-----------+   |   |   |
|                   |   |   |
|   +-------+   +---+   |   |
|   |       |   |       |   |
|   |   +---+   +---+   |   |
|   |   |           |   |   |
+---+   +-----------+   +---+


Optional `n` = 12

+---+   +-----------+   +-------------------+
|   |   |           |   |                   |
|   |   +-------+   |   +---+   +-----------+
|   |           |   |       |   |           
|   +-------+   |   +-------+   +---+   +---+
|           |   |                   |   |   |
|   +-------+   +---+   +-------+   |   |   |
|   |               |   |       |   |   |   |
|   +---------------+   |   +---+   +---+   |
|                       |   |               |
|   +-------+   +-------+   +-----------+   |
|   |       |   |                       |   |
|   |   +---+   |   +-------------------+   |
|   |   |       |   |                       |
|   |   +-------+   +-----------------------+
|   |                                       
|   +-------------------------------+   +---+
|                                   |   |   |
+-------+   +-------+   +---+   +---+   |   |
        |   |       |   |   |   |       |   |
+-------+   +---+   |   |   |   +-------+   |
|               |   |   |   |               |
+---------------+   +---+   +---------------+

+---+   +---------------------------+   +---+
|   |   |                           |   |   |
|   |   |   +-------+   +-----------+   |   |
|   |   |   |       |   |               |   |
|   |   |   +---+   |   +-------+   +---+   |
|   |   |       |   |           |   |       |
|   |   +---+   |   |   +---+   |   |   +---+
|   |       |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
|   +-------+   |   +---+   |   +---+   +---+
|               |           |               |
+---+   +---+   |   +---+   +-------+   +---+
    |   |   |   |   |   |           |   |   
+---+   |   |   +---+   +---+   +---+   +---+
|       |   |               |   |           |
|   +---+   +---------------+   +---+   +---+
|   |                               |   |   
|   +-----------+   +---+   +-------+   +---+
|               |   |   |   |               |
|   +-------+   |   |   |   |   +-------+   |
|   |       |   |   |   |   |   |       |   |
|   |   +---+   |   |   +---+   +---+   |   |
|   |   |       |   |               |   |   |
+---+   +-------+   +---------------+   +---+

+---------------------------+   +---+   +---+
|                           |   |   |   |   |
|   +---------------+   +---+   |   +---+   |
|   |               |   |       |           |
|   |   +---+   +---+   +-------+   +---+   |
|   |   |   |   |                   |   |   |
|   +---+   |   +---------------+   |   |   |
|           |                   |   |   |   |
+-------+   +---+   +-----------+   |   |   |
        |       |   |               |   |   |
+---+   |   +---+   |   +-----------+   |   |
|   |   |   |       |   |               |   |
|   +---+   |   +---+   |   +-----------+   |
|           |   |       |   |               |
|   +-------+   +---+   |   |   +-------+   |
|   |               |   |   |   |       |   |
|   |   +-----------+   |   |   |   +---+   |
|   |   |               |   |   |   |       |
|   |   |   +-------+   |   +---+   +---+   |
|   |   |   |       |   |               |   |
|   |   |   |   +---+   +-------+   +---+   |
|   |   |   |   |               |   |       |
+---+   +---+   +---------------+   +-------+
```

Falsy:

```
Optional `n` = 6

; Two paths
+-------------------+
|                   |
|   +-----------+   |
|   |           |   |
|   +-----------+   |
|                   |
+-------+   +-------+
        |   |       
+-------+   +-------+
|                   |
+-------------------+

; Two paths
+-------+   +-------+
|       |   |       |
|   +---+   +-------+
|   |               
|   +---------------+
|                   |
|   +-----------+   |
|   |           |   |
|   +---+   +---+   |
|       |   |       |
+-------+   +-------+

; The path doesn't visit each vertex
+-----------+   +---+
|           |   |   |
|           |   |   |
|           |   |   |
+-------+   +---+   |
        |           |
+---+   +---+   +---+
|   |       |   |   
|   +-------+   +---+
|                   |
+-------------------+

; The path doesn't visit each vertex and touches itself
; (so visits some points more than once)
+-------------------+
|                   |
|   +-----------+   |
|   |           |   |
|   |   +-------+   |
|   |   |           |
|   |   +-------+   |
|   |           |   |
+---+-----------+   |
    |               |
    +---------------+

; The path doesn't form a loop and touches itself
+---+   +---+   +---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   | 
+---+---+   +---+---+

Optional `n` = 8

; Two paths
+-------------------+   +---+
|                   |   |   |
|   +-----------+   |   |   |
|   |           |   |   |   |
|   +-------+   |   +---+   |
|           |   |           |
+-------+   |   +-----------+
        |   |               
+---+   +---+   +-----------+
|   |           |           |
|   |   +---+   |   +-------+
|   |   |   |   |   |       
|   +---+   +---+   +-------+
|                           |
+---------------------------+

; The path doesn't visit each vertex
+---------------+   +-------+
|               |   |       |
|   +-------+   +---+       |
|   |       |               |
|   |   +---+   +---+       |
|   |   |       |   |       |
|   |   +-------+   +-------+
|   |                       
|   |   +-------------------+
|   |   |                   |
|   +---+   +---+   +---+   |
|           |   |   |   |   |
|   +---+   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+


; The path doesn't visit each vertex
+---------------+   +-------+
|               |   |       |
|   +-----------+   +---+   |
|   |                   |   |
|   +---+   +-----------+   |
|       |   |               |
+---+   |   +-------+   +---+
    |   |           |   |   
+---+   +-------+   |   |    
|               |   |   |    
|   +-----------+   |   |    
|   |               |   |   
|   +---------------+   +---+
|                           |
+---------------------------+

; Two paths
+-----------+   +-----------+
|           |   |           |
|   +---+   |   |   +-------+
|   |   |   |   |   |       
|   |   |   |   |   +-------+
|   |   |   |   |           |
+---+   |   |   +-------+   |
        |   |           |   |
+---+   |   +-----------+   |
|   |   |                   |
|   |   |   +-----------+   |
|   |   |   |           |   |
|   +---+   +-----------+   |
|                           |
+---------------------------+

; The path touches itself (so visits some points more than once)
+---+   +-------------------+
|   |   |                   |
|   |   |   +---+   +-------+
|   |   |   |   |   |       
|   +---+   |   |   |   +---+
|           |   |   |   |   |
+---+   +---+   |   |   |   |
    |   |       |   |   |   |
+---+   +-------+---+---+   |
|               |   |       |
+-------+   +---+   +---+   |
        |   |           |   |
+-------+   +-----------+   |
|                           |
+---------------------------+

; The path doesn't form a loop
+---------------+   +-------+
|               |           |
+-------+   +   +-------+   |
        |   |           |   |
+-------+   +-----------+   |
|                           |
|   +-------------------+   |
|   |                   |   |
|   +---+   +-----------+   |
|       |   |               |
|   +---+   +-----------+   |
|   |                   |   |
|   +---------------+   |   |
|                   |   |   |
+-------------------+   +---+
```

### Wining criteria:

The shortest solution in bytes in each language wins.
I'll highly appreciate if you add explanation of the code and the algorithm you used.

Comment: Do we have to use the ASCII representation given? Or can we use an alternative ASCII representation?

Comment: Are we allowed to take inputs drawn with only a single `-` (rather than `---`) as the horizontal connector?

Comment: @Nick Kennedy Yes, you can.

Comment: @Jonah Yes, you can.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>63</s> <s>55</s> 46 bytes

```
ＡＭ↗ Ｗ⁼№ＫＶ#¹«✳⊗⁻¹⌕ＫＶ#¦ ¿¬∨﹪ⅈ⁴﹪ⅉ²⊞υω»¿‹ＬυＸＮ²⎚«⎚¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRRT8IwEH5mv@JSXrpkPkB8kkfQxERwMdFoCA9jVNZYWtxWeDD@9nkDRNa1hdik3V2v3329b7elWZKnKhFVFedclvRernVJw3AQjNWG0Zvn9RNfZiX6@zgBgvY244IBvf3UiSjoUGmMxIx9vCg5YXqVSEnDCEiX4NoLQ/gKOnv4iOcsLbmSdKT0XLAFHXOpC9qL4I7LhSMJDjR2zB3@DnSiSvqY07FaaKHoa33sGufBf6v9fg2CWBcZ1RFsEfkd1NAHVhS4yGWJATwXqy3L91VP9GqO9gEMQ8ES9AYBEwWrKzhuHGrp1UmrajoNSNc3AKDxJBECwD265vwFeDOf2keAIzMYsQbAemdzrwEwMltradRwymTWYwLAcl@rUjuAS3MXg5ndp9ofg6mUi8WmkpfFqZKLxaaSl6XVSyaDGTvXSy3GVi/ZtPf10lmWlqwmwyXdetl7sN33v99DuwZfp5p7ZIa/0v6sutqIHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 8 bytes by using a more cumbersome but still acceptable input format. Saved 9 bytes by requiring the path only uses `#`s. Explanation:

```
Ａ
```

Copy the path to the canvas.

```
Ｍ↗
```

Print a space one square in from the bottom-left corner (the print command left the cursor one square below the bottom-left corner). This should break the loop of `#`s into a line.

```
Ｗ⁼№ＫＶ#¹«
```

Try to follow the line to its end, following the path of `#`s that used to have two neighbours.

```
✳⊗⁻¹⌕ＫＶ#¦
```

Overwrite the line as we go.

```
¿¬∨﹪ⅈ⁴﹪ⅉ²⊞υω»
```

Keep track of how many vertices we meet along the way.

```
 ¿‹ＬυＸＮ²⎚
```

Check whether we managed to visit every vertex. If not, then just clear the canvas.

```
«⎚¹
```

If we visited every vertex then output `1` as a truthy value (which actually prints as `-`).

Comment: You can use alternatve ASCII representation.

Comment: @GalenIvanov Would [this](https://tio.run/##nVRNT8JAED3TXzGplyFbDhBPchRNTASJX9EYDgVWunHdxbYLMdbfXqeApG67hThJ25mdffN2XqedRWE806HM83EsVIrDcIlXamlSbAdwl9LaolgSAdzzWIXxJ17zJEEf/AAkbfFPNg5Z3xvqFcezh@WtWEQpxduKtJX8dSQkB7z4MKFM8Fwbyow5f3vUasTNe6gUbqvRvdtuw5fX2sIHIuazVGiFA22mks9xKJRJsBvApVBzRxEycjbMLfEKONIp3sQ41HMjNT4V207p2sXPRdwrQDA2SYQmgDUhv70Cuun3mqtFSgnaN9ZrHm81Gpn3Kfk7MJxLHlLU97hMeNHBfmHXS7comucvL57POm5jAMDKTz/w/AzcltnXL4A1VM7K/i8gc1QGK/cHwGrOXGErAzKrcm0v5R7K57X7qQCg5ry1ShUA5tDcyWBXb1Jtz1DR28VSp1Iji0slJ0udSo0s9izZM2TnDs5ShdGepVrtm2bpIIsNYBYDO2Zaj3oPdef99/dQ6YE1TGrHZvMn9CvtTfLOSv4A) be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable.

Comment: @GalenIvanov How about [this](https://tio.run/##nVRRT8IwEH5mv@JSXrpkPkB8kkfQxERwMdFoCA9jVNZYWtxWeDD@9nkDRNa1hdik3V2v3329b7elWZKnKhFVFedclvRernVJw3AQjNWG0Zvn9RNfZiX6@zgBgvY244IBvf3UiSjoUGmMxIx9vCg5YXqVSEnDCEiX4NoLQ/gKOnv4iOcsLbmSdKT0XLAFHXOpC9qL4I7LhSMJDjR2zB3@DnSiSvqY07FaaKHoa33sGufBf6v9fg2CWBcZ1RFsEfkd1NAHVhS4yGWJATwXqy3L91VP9GqO9gEMQ8ES9AYBEwWrKzhuHGrp1UmrajoNSNc3AKDxJBECwD265vwFeDOf2keAIzMYsQbAemdzrwEwMltradRwymTWYwLAcl@rUjuAS3MXg5ndp9ofg6mUi8WmkpfFqZKLxaaSl6XVSyaDGTvXSy3GVi/ZtPf10lmWlqwmwyXdetl7sN33v99DuwZfp5p7ZIa/0v6sutqIHw)?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. You can even have only one # horizontally instead of ###

Comment: @GalenIvanov Thanks, but I think it would be possible to fool the algorithm in that case.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 34 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ø1©ȧn⁶µŒṪạ®SỊƊƇḢ©Wḟ@ƲƬṖṪ<3Ȧȧm2m€4Ȧ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of characters (the lines) which yields `1` for a Hamiltonian or `0` otherwise. Uses the layout in the question (any non-space chars as path parts will work).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMNDK08sz3vUuO3Q1qOTHu5c9XDXwkPrgh/u7jrWdaz94Y5Fh1aGP9wx3@HYpmNrHu6cBlRgY3xi2YnluUa5j5rWmJxY9v/h7i2H2///19ZFAG0FBQUQX5urRgEBamCYJFFtdDPBosjq4GwubTR1CDfUoJkLFtTG61xUY9GBNgA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##zVq7blRBDO3nK6a3puDRhYJ/oOALaFBCj@Qi0ERKSYEoQCggJQqKKBCghHQbsdrfuPsjS4jgvuxje@7eIFbaYie@vjN@HB978vTJ7u7zzebqzZ3F6erk2frF98W3n6@ai0/Nj6PF50fN5eHycHnQnH9YnD5uzt8/XH5ZnjUXr68FHtxbHa9O9u7urV@e3V8db5rLr83Fx/X@2531/rurg@vVzYZK96Gc8@/flDh3H/77vVmlnmy3KuQHsq38QG8rn6j37k62/@5Ob192uAe5X/1sO4P19u9gb@NzdLJj@XaRVFEWavvyJFal2Ums1h2ZJu5NyvL4yFhUWpKEbP8YrVpdVKrVT6Y72Xa2o7O1Ztb28ecr4pPcvNItxOqzrOVE/7WqijQ28ECFmn4yJoWVYHrY6T60MvYQSFPVlDgPSM0dIS@epdGqnaMyd1R/JBQ1BmSq@a6fl9DzasTm4LMxO5cK3LHxB9uSIASPdaiZJJNfNYkAH/pHLmSUguK9sipqppLPclXomKWjyqUxFxeAfLjqhkKgKGFQB8xxVxF0OwNdfgghs9gIa4d2AYgv0Zsdm@AQ9CtDWL8aJmTWdqvyZBQmsBiZRSdehApCFbUoZVBoAgVOcGkUfnqYEDq/yoVtkNdt6LmIVewyw1UtznbhUwu8S4SQ3iGp0vTC38ny@fibLMBkE9mysmXMfBEY60wYciKNolo1lvwaHeotign2HMxitaRji9QlGqOaAZPYCxIbj@MUwTI77hhKRcNdQrU4O/bE9TLGwDXAtRkohQAiziFQrbS7fdMuiRzgxt1Q3Pcmxd4CkMP6U5QKZp9em7mW3WLMlg3MDtLVDwsgm@1JfQHkreMbTxUsfCgzDOVoxkGk3Jt2PiDK4UFH/8i6DhkGeCTmUto5Lal3INL7npcj4@boqh6xKudJ5JICSLVoCy/fhjswcLHfZwO9N2cUe9DpYg50BHiCyc7Q@79cza2B2oPNMK/0B0exoZPOeDBxRhMSjHy5j4BUNavxx6QFxwm6G/ABePrE2datA/QYhbLK3XOIZ2aXm9uzEbvVUWlLzXDWnpL6lJ0qsg7d/5HTakx14dSLEDLpBptNN7tNtnndNMaNbHaj2cScbDJgu@maMQkJzu5jN2iVuAL7b@fWx@4lsjUwSn6P44/P/Wd5YsBOd@G2tz7@HbBZGlidsWFMImOWCv4XAY9DegSBk98mwblwIHTKLbqwDkdBGzUhHaaeKXblMD9@@8/WXaDPcvn6Cw).

#### How?

Starts at the top-left, `[1,1]`, and finds a neighbouring non-space until no neighbours can be found, then checks if the final position is the neighbour below the top-left, `[2,1]`, (to confirm the path was a loop) and that no other non-spaces remain (to confirm there were not multiple paths). If so a final check is made that all the vertices were non-spaces too.

```
Ø1©ȧn⁶µŒṪạ®SỊƊƇḢ©Wḟ@ƲƬṖṪ<3Ȧȧm2m€4Ȧ - Link: list of lines, M
Ø1                                 - literal [1,1]
  ©                                - (copy this to the register and yield it)
   ȧ                               - logical AND (with M) -> M 
     ⁶                             - literal space character
    n                              - not equal? (vectorises)
      µ                            - new monadic chain, call that N
       ŒṪ                          - truthy multidimensional indices
                     Ƭ             - collect up while distinct, applying:
                    Ʋ              -   last four links as a monad:
              Ƈ                    -     filter keep if (find neighbours):
             Ɗ                     -       last three links as a monad:
         ạ                         -         absolute difference (vectorises):
          ®                        -           current register value
           S                       -         sum
            Ị                      -         insignificant? (abs(z)<=1)
               Ḣ                   -     head (a neighbour [x,y] or 0 if none)
                ©                  -     (copy this to the register and yield it)
                 W                 -     wrap in a list
                   @               -     with swapped arguments:
                  ḟ                -       filter discard
                      Ṗ            - remove rightmost
                       Ṫ           - get rightmost (or 0 if none)
                        <3         - less than three? (vectorises)
                          Ȧ        - all non-zero when flattened?
                           ȧ       - logical AND (with N) -> 
                                   - (i.e. N if the entire path looped from [1,1]
                                   -  back to [2,1] leaving nothing unconsumed
                                   -  else 0)
                            m2     - every 2nd value
                              m€4  - every 4th value of each
                                 Ȧ - all non-zero when flattened?
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>126 124</s>  122 bytes

Takes input as `(n)(matrix)`. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
n=>g=(m,X=k=0,Y=0,d=0)=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>++c|(x-X)**2+(y-Y)**2-1||g(m,x,r[++d,x%4|y%2||k++,x]=y)))|d>1?k=g:k==n*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VpRSxtBEH73VyyCeOfcBhUp0nLpW39BH5Q0DyHRtI1JJNqSwP73NLYYj8vOzDebSyIVAh7Lzt7Nzn7fNzP7s/e799Sf/Xh89pPp4G55Xy4nZXtYZuPiphyV58Xt6jcoz/OyPW6Ne49ZNisWq4fZv4d@MV89EPVDNvc3@dnZJWULf/vyj78IYbgyMy9mHaJBMT@5CouTyxBGRMW8Wy7yPA@D9sXnUTn8OCrLydlk2Z9OnqYPd62H6TA77Xyd/Xr@vuie5p@OqgP32Yc86xw512m1Wsfk3/7IOffyTMfd4nU8uLe/8PqrjVNlfmx8wwYzf22DWX9tozJOlfeOza@@d2z96nzu/aXvZ/x31M1Xbgf9vp5v@O6632LzN2xExkmZH4T1qzZIGJfihoTxXfmdGvxuaX4Q/I7Ml/adhPlVv8XW1@ZL6zP@i/r9Wol3NO7h94jgl4t9z@uzgANkwENtn4JiL8Qwinm/qN3a97qYLQA3pXO8sRcAHqF4zu2vEC9J8abtJ4I3pODWhg3BHtXGURyVcCkaJxofo7ys4LTmP@JsKufVbWHPur/ewCvXCq@g/ILsJwE8v2FXwSMJf6N7IPAIvbN4Cxy2Ce8n6cTYfkj2QuJ5kOLt4lITMokBaA1IzxAbIkStAesjQZtK0CkBQ0BABsa@JeA5n6IEih5YzxC/RNhB8SdyYCwCAV5TiU8CBackShwQn6xQAQVHigDxHPgqgsQxgsIkeISEmzsLWnwS57t4opsGkOgGaUERFOQXD5ei8FAFFFWOBkXPrcVlDLG12GcFQLgfQgBIRuViWTAQgCSsgWSYrFJXMjpJTZFFoRkrBx4k1AACllMUHeLPVAAJHFkDgKXFJ0pwKQpR2kckY/fbKEgVGI0MFhIUjzVljbEZmkKRESBTFCSndtBSp@hThaGRFEoqESEBKKaSDRMcvCaQAaQoZDICiDMorCD5DywJqWsCAgXJOLYVKKHB84eUNCVw5BXk6bdJ50vv4cnSNGuieQMVTRpumnmhCRCVE4b56PqIpo/5XVtXOgFI88OS8x1i37XagHRCsJPQfJN4m3ENMZyiBMggcZFUhPYc74eMN4T5EAWWsv5fPwvvr6V0zlA74JrESNMuOHvz@38cd/WNWzvvQF07S1fB2qXQUhYkJ@cK3BAhM8RMiUV5S1fRIwcCuH1gERD76BKj76MJjDpZOaXm4IwprDPUFNAiOVzzUVKYbbueaFfRUnKgFEADbotRQpd4V/HW5C0OAhMMpKjP1qW3vKVTx3MH1hAdyA8OLUGhJa4D45vGBym3mprgA7ZOm3ALBi3ZOKn3ocSvN5RkkBKMB0suTZzXfcTbLm7BWG4tovojKD0rhF9IaJCqt5CRGn9FR4cEfhAbxYnnwb@zeEvlU7Uw1hB@NOkv6yWKffO9xV7qrdJd3/Jb/gE)

#### How?

Starting at \$(0,0)\$, we flood-fill the path and increment a counter \$k\$ each time we go through a cell \$(x,y)\$ such that \$x\equiv 0\pmod 4\$ and \$y\equiv 0\pmod 2\$.

At the end of the process, we must have \$k=n^2\$.

We additionally make sure that no cell has more than 2 neighbors. If it does happen, we set \$k\$ to a non-numeric value to force the final test to fail.

Comment: You can use alternatve ASCII representation.

Comment: @GalenIvanov Thanks for the notification. That would not help much in my case, because I'm just testing space vs not-space.

Comment: Can we take the input as a matrix of zeros and ones?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 54 bytes

```
n⁶,Z$µØ0jm2N,¹ƇɗƝ)m2)Z×LƊ€2¦Ẏ€;"/µØ-ḟN}Ḣɗ,+¥ƭƒịṪ¥¥ƬL=L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVi9bhNBEO7vKUYoTTRegdJGoDxAlAdITxMl9EiLFGgsEYkCilAQIYFCgUIHVky6s7CUxzi/iDnfz@43P2c7CKfI3u7c7sw33/zsnTw/PX25XL5YvJ6MjnfKX7OPT07O9o5G5XQ@vr@cX@2e7e0ezy4P528Xb272ym/V73f1YP/R45VoqG4/H72qbr/cX464vJ7/mL@v7i6q6ffyun66OXx6uNxfnH8qJ@EZLc6v9qu7n7PxTvHnQzX92swflJN6fjautzxpJprn5ZLD6sfEgYtIq19c/dVjbubbcVrp5puVTr5ZKbjZo51v92jl2/l@n7w/nnvQPTUzYtf@tHY@rTRjhvmY5NsVTuNsDafxsBa8dtc8H5MWcj5rzWm@Pa2Vx/ksj@ciFhoPI93oTQT@qU/pEWfjVdQuwnrM/ureB5mi17@TAU9nnJN2wmeaJb3@0j7hfdBYeonBg2klrXcrxvPZf2AV8llzGhiC5zNKAOLkrnv6hwGmabZJjVlwP8mADzNHQKfENP5HiyMJzMX5UeiX1@MAYia2Biz3EAjAVJkFPERCwmSI/b6FLJAAzzqIoUaa3doDASIlR0NU@khEbfS4bwA@rLKFjDcS@IjIU7Hmx1xAHkHsEYm8oWM01QJEE/Fh1AKyvI4N1FTbFoF7CmfIAjpaIVOYPIbSfb7L0uJ/IVFIpxWSt1ExkQgqAuRT5DnmdZHJID/LCGebA5xqFFRkRMfzBLlB6jPkyYjxIzyv8dFM93OItEHWmzDQNQQn5knpK2PYqweZ2ToLs8MUP6dgBOuOQ2lUsOK/rG8@Eirzb2C6@0bhZlCb9ZUnycR8JFVHVCSpN0SkRlWdhiM1bsRfdiaSJ2Gr/pK37nLzrhBlYj66vU6vBUplXGRfaHP29lpjXcq4WCy8jt8fI/KQvwo2uUTmP96IxcNsk3yMtk8Q8vXpaR/MtuTUGtkHR3N3@P/jlXbNqVv1v7Zb87o5zGeyAmBnpJjbsZcHeizbPweJFF5rbABsavj1GxgQPekISgk5iZlM6dDNkSl1kLiG2m/dPttCwr5rxaWXTalab/H6SxWrpBRVExFN86AvhT2FSBVzUhQjXRJ16dzaxyyuKN411CcVwbNeR4sjfHQQNhe26NkLhl2PaxHfZPHmS539BIAWi4usYR2LBlt8ZpGNUmDTepNqN3zEwoMtHmK1KJdrfLT@RO8y9JCosOtDnyq2urj/BQ)

A monadic link which takes a list of strings as input and returns a boolean. The strings use the format of the question but omitting every other character (so half the width). Full explanation to follow.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 125 bytes

```
p=.((,-)#:1 2)|.!.0]
f=.([:(''-:2 0~.@-.~[:,]*+/@p)' '~:])*1-1 e.[:([:,@(,]+1=(2|#\)*/4|#\@|:)([:>./]*"2 p)^:_)_(<0 0)}' '~:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVpLbxNBDL7PrzD0kGzd2SYRp6WpIg4cOXEroUKoDyEkKh4HJNO/HtIUNpsdf/bMJkVUippOvM6MH58/e/pptbqb1@PxSayOminNKqmf1ZNluF4vXjTj0Sg2M5rc14tY3180J8tjPl3cVSMa3TfL6ngap3RVr@XWHy3GJ0uezsczOXpXHZ@@WP9aSFOtPzqvT5fHz2d0V71vLqvL8dmEJtWvRx2rm3lNFw1dL5rzl/Xl7OH92ebNMoQ3r2p6@/XH99uf4erj7Re6oQk1k8Bx@8NE9PA3B6Htj/x9bVa5I7tdTeR3ZFv5Hb2t/GYP3Ncdut@91duV3d1Dul/9bPOd9fZzsLf@Obayffl2kVVRSdR25TlZTc3OyWrZkXng3lJZ6R8Zi6aW5ES2e4xWrS6aqtVPpjvZdrajs7Umafv480rik9280i0k6rOi5UT3a1UVoW/gHRVq@qUxmVgJpoed7rtWxh4CaaqaEucBq7mTyCfPcm/VztE0d1R/BBQ1BmSq@a6fl9HzasRS5rN5do4FuGPjD7YlQwju61AzKU1@1SQJ@PA/cqGgFEy@N62KmqnSZ6UodMzSUeTSPBdHgHy46maFQFTCoAyY813F0O0CdPkhhMxiI6wd2hEgfore4tgEh6BfGbL1q2HCZm23Kg@hMIHFyCw6@UUoIlRRixKBQpNR4BIujcJPDxNG51e5sA3yug09F4mKXWa4qsXZLnxqgXeJENK7S6o0vfDvYPm8/woWYIqJbKRsGTNfBMY6E4acSKOoVo1lv0Zn9RbRBHvJzGK1pGOLlCWaoJoBk9gLEhuP8ymCZXbcMcSChjtm1WJy7InrZR4D1wDXZqCcBRD5HALVSrvbN@0S2AFu3A3l@96k2HsAcrb@kEsFyafXZq6RW4zFsoHZQbr6YQEUsz0pL4Cyd3zjqYKFD39JRPU4onz94fM3PKEsndbxASeU6aa1gwNRyZ6AdPFS15HGB56VuVz3kJbUW5M0LDT3l86hc1f1UFbJUGCXLUAOxnt4@SncgRFN/AYc6N2cMdmDziMpo1XAo01xpuH/5Sq1BmoPdoBBpj9RyptG6VQIM2o0OsHIR10E5KIhjj8/jThO0KWBD8DDR9G2bh2g@yhEKqmnLAJKLmm3hyZ2D6TymZKprT0@9bk8F2QduhhkpwcZ6sKhNyRs0g0xu3Fxu2/zHqqPG2S2qWRiDpnU2O7GDpiEDIf6eVdrhbgCG3PnOshuMsiaJAW/@fHn6v6zMjBgh7tw3@sg/3LYLA2iDt8wJrExZAX/pIDnJB2CIMHvn@DAOCN04hO6sAxHQRs1IB2GninvLuLw@O0/W3azfqhb2Wr1Gw)

Just a first draft, but all test cases are passing.  Will attempt to golf and add explanation this week.